# I can not get selection input with string keys

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 8 app with laravelcollective/html 6.2 and php7.4 I need to fill selection input with method in model :

```
private static $userStatusLabelValueArray = ['N' => 'New(Waiting activation)', 'A' => 'Active', 'I' => 'Inactive', 'B'=>'Banned'];

public static function getUserStatusValueArray($key_return = true): array
{
    $resArray = [];
    foreach (self::$userStatusLabelValueArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<pre>$key::'.print_r($key,true).'</pre>';
        echo '<pre>$value::'.print_r($value,true).'</pre>';
        if ($key_return) {
            $resArray[] = ['key' => $key, 'label' => $value];
        } else {
            $resArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $resArray;
}
```

debugging I see that $key has valid string value but when $key_return is false I got array with
keys 0...3, not 'N', 'A' as I expected.

Which way is valid ?

Thanks!

Comment: Cannot reproduce. But you're overcomplicating things - when `$key_return = false`, you're expecting the exact same array as `$userStatusLabelValueArray`, so you could simply return it without rebuilding it from scratch.

Comment: Thasnks!, that was my silly issue